# Angular ng show does not update while the scope does

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am setting up a `<button>` that is supposed to open a chat window.

the chat window has a `ng-show` depending on `scope.openChat` which is `false` to start.
When I clicked the button I update scope.openChat to true and use `$scope.apply`. 
The scope seems to have updated but the `ng-show` does not do anything.

here is the html

```
<div ng-controller="MessagesCtrl">
    <button start-chat>Send Messages</button>
</div>
```

and

```
<div ng-show="openChat" ng-controller="MessagesCtrl">
    <div>CHAT WINDOW
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the controller:

```
app.controller("MessagesCtrl", function MessagesCtrl($scope,Auth) {
    $scope.openChat = false;
    $scope.message = { recipient : undefined, sender: undefined, text:'text'};
});
```

Here is the directive for the button:

```
'use strict';
app.directive('startChat',[ 'Post', 'Auth', function (Post, Auth) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'MessagesCtrl',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.openChat = true;
                    scope.message.recipient = scope.profile.$id;
                    scope.message.sender = Auth.resolveUser().uid;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

thank you

Comment: MessagesCtrl will have 2 instances. You can put it in the rootScope  or some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not creating two instances of `MessagesCtrl`. Here is a simplified working example of the issue you are trying to solve. Examine the markup and see that `MessagesCtrl` contains both of these elements. Otherwise, you were on the right track updating `$scope` and calling `$apply`

Also note that `.on()` is the preferred method to `.bind()` see **[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)**

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xuLncxrp/)

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MessagesCtrl">
        <button start-chat>Send Messages</button>
        <div class="chatWindow" ng-show="openChat"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
app.directive('startChat', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.openChat = true;
                });
             });
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('MessagesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.openChat = false;
    $scope.message = { recipient : undefined, sender: undefined, text:'text'};
}]);
```